# Can "each" be substituted by "either" in a construction like "There were two girls, either with a flower"?

Tags: word-choice

Can "each" be substituted by "either" in a construction like

> There were two girls, either with a flower?

And if so, is it clear that totally there are *two* flowers?

Is it crucial that the sentence is affirmative? Will

"There were two girls, neither had a flower"

sound better?

Comment: My instinct is to say no.  *Either* usually refers to a choice between options, not to both, as in "You can choose either the fish or the steak."  There are some cases where it can mean both, as in "Bodyguards stood on either side of the Leader" but I don't feel like this is one of them.  But I admit I don't have a very good reference for why.

Comment: I would agree with @stangdon here. You would usually use either when talking about two or more alternatives (e.g. in your example of bodyguards, there is side X and side Y - alternative sides), but in this context all we know is that they are **both** girls and **both** have a flower, so 'each' seems a better fit.

Comment: But what is the essential difference betwee sides and girls? One might as well say:  "there is girl A and girl B - alternative girls"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your sentence

> There were two girls, either with a flower

sounds awkward, I think you probably mean

> There were two girls, either **one** had a flower

"Either one" means both people and since you are saying they have flowers with them, the possessive "had" is used.

Only using "either with a flower" leaves the reader suspended since they would be waiting for something like

> either with a flower *or with a ribbon*

Using "either one" would mean both have flowers and there would be two flowers.

> There were two girls, neither had a flower

is understandable since you are using the possessive "had" meaning there were no flowers.  If you had used

> There were two girls, neither with a flower

a similar ambiguity would occur

> neither with a flower *nor with something else*

would be expected.

Comment: "either one had a flower" is not correct (it implies that one or the other, but not both, had a flower, and the structure is still awkward), while there is nothing wrong, only a little old-fashioned, about "neither with a flower".

Comment: "If either one had a flower", or "before either one had a flower", or "when either one had a flower", or "neither one had a flower", but not "There were two girls, either one had a flower."

Comment: "either *one* had a flower" = "either *girl* had a flower" = "*both girls* had flowers", 1. used as a determiner: You use either in front of the singular form of a countable noun to say that something is true about each of two people or things [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/either).